# Is selling education for money is sin in Kali yuga?

Tags: guru, artha

The following lines are from the [footnotes](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a164.htm) of the Mahabharata

> In India, from the remotest times, preceptors are excluded from
>   charging their pupils any fees for the instruction they give. No
>   doubt, a final fee, called Gurudakshina, is demandable, but that is
>   demandable after the pupil has completed his studies. **To sell
>   knowledge for money is a great sin**. To this day in all the indigenous
>   tols of the country, instruction is imparted free of all charges. In
>   addition to this, the pupils are fed by their preceptors. The latter,
>   in their turn, are supported by the charity of the whole country.

Although above lines say that selling education for money is a sin. It is not an explicit statement from scripture.

Is there any explicit statement from scriptures saying about correctness of selling education for money in Kali yuga?

Comment: The Guru that you are talking about is Shiksha Guru but the Guru that is (mostly) talked about in the scriptures is the Diksha Guru or the spiritual teacher.

Comment: @Rickross I'm asking about siksha guru...

Comment: Yes selling real education/Dharma Shastras for money is sin whether its shiksha or diksha, education in original Vedic times was supported by Guru Dakshina i.e. public funds or king's treasury in times of shortage, but in Kaliyuga the education which is mostly machinery skills and devoid of Dharma and morality, that is taught, keeping in mind with the purpose of filling belly for this life only, not to be taken for eternal life of any jivatma(as majority people are dumber, shortlived and atheist), is sold for money.